# What files can I delete to avoid repeating the Python libraries?

Tags: python, package-management, libraries, metapackages

I installed `SAGE mathematics` from binary because there was no package for it in `synaptic`. From [reading on the web](http://vnoel.wordpress.com/2008/05/03/bye-matlab-hello-python-thanks-sage/) I learned that `SAGE` brings its own `python` libraries rather than using the ones Ubuntu / `synaptic` has already installed.

I'm getting low on hard disk space -- what can/should I delete? Or how should I rejigger my libraries / system to avoid duplicating (gigabytes) worth of libraries?

BTW, I'm having a similar problem with `texlive-full` -- I first downloaded the package in `synaptic`, then realised it was outdated, then downloaded the `iso` -- and now I think I have three or four copies of `LaTeX` on my drive.

Comment: Ouch.  If there's any possible way to increase your disk space (cloud storage? cheap disk? usb drive?) I would strongly recommend that.  Not that this isn't worthwhile, but I'm guessing you'll save time and stress down the line if you can take care of that first.  (Unless you are slimming down/optimizing your install to procrastinate, or to be OCD, etc..)

Comment: @jgbelacqua I'm really short on money; I bought this drive for $30 from a used parts store. It's 30 GB which should be sufficient with no media files. All I Really Need to get work done is `R Studio`, `LaTeX`, a text editor, and `Chrome`. Want to be able to program in `php`, `ruby`, `perl`, `python`, `c++`.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the downsides of installing software from outside of the standard repositories. For most people, it isn't a big problem, but for you it appears to be an issue due to disk space.

The apps you've downloaded use their own versions of various libraries and software components, and have been tested to work with those components. Removing them will likely cause those programs to be unstable or stop working.

It sounds like you would be safe to remove the texlive-related packages that you've installed via your package manager. That will free up some disk space, as texlive packages are pretty large.

I would recommend:

```
sudo apt-get remove texlive* && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean
```

That will remove the texlive packages you installed, remove any dependencies that are no longer needed, and then clear your cache of packages you previously installed.

As another commenter suggested, though, you might want to consider a backup drive, or (if you can afford it) even a new, larger hard drive. Hard drives are not so expensive these days.

Comment: Will that `autoremove` be different than the warning `synaptic` gave me that it would delete `teXmacs`?

Comment: autoremove only removes dependencies that are no longer needed, or software that has been replaced by an upgrade. For example, autoremove would remove a gedit-plugins package if you have removed gedit. Or it would remove older kernel versions after you have successfully updated your kernel.